# Incremental Future of list extensions

Tags: java, concurrency, future

I essentially have a `Future<List<T>>` that is fetched in batches from the server. For some clients I'd like to provide incremental results while it loads in addition to the whole collection when future is fulfilled.

Is there a common Future extension defined somewhere for this? What are typical patterns/combinators exist for such futures?

I assume that given `IncrementalListFuture<T>` I can easily define `map` operation. What else comes to your mind?

Comment: Wow, I did misread it.  Do you mean a Future<List<T>> where the `List` is being added to in the background?  Or do you mean multiple Futures?

Comment: @Gray he wishes to be notified of the `List<T>` being built gradually, which `Future` itself does not support. He really should try refactoring it to use `List<Future<T>>`, which seems more appropriate.

Comment: Why is it more appropriate? It is not really possible to turn `Future<List<T>>` into `List<Future<T>>` unless you know the collection size in advance, right?

Comment: I've edited my answer @mikea.  You are correct that if there is an unknown number of results, you can't use a `List<Future<T>>`.  Sorry for the misread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: there has been lots of development in this area recently. Among most used are: Play iteratees (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Iteratees) and Rx for .NET (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx)

Instead of Future they define something like:

```
interface Observable<T> {
    Disposable subscribe(Observer<T> observer);
}

interface Observer<T> {
   void onCompleted();
   void onError(Exception error);
   void onNext(T value);
}
```

and lots of combinators.

Comment: Curious how is this better than the `ExecutorCompletionService`?  You like want the callback pattern?

Comment: oh, sorry, didn't want to actually downvote that. ExecutorCompletionService has nothing to do with this. The question is about incremental futures. I.e. futures that generate stream of events/items. ExecutoreCompletionService is just a utility to execute lots of individual futures.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a common Future extension defined somewhere for this?

I assume you are talking about incremental results from an `ExecutorService`.  You should consider using an [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) which allows you to be informed as soon as one of the `Future` objects is get-able.

To quote from the javadocs:

```
CompletionService<Result> ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<Result>(e);
for (Callable<Result> s : solvers) {
    ecs.submit(s);
}
int n = solvers.size();
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    // this waits for one of the futures to finish and provide a result
    Future<Result> future = ecs.take();
    Result result = future.get();
    if (result != null) {
        // do something with the result
    }
}
```

---

*Sorry.  I initially misread the question and thought that you were asking about a List<Future<?>>.  It may be that you could refactor your code to actually return a number of Futures so I'll leave this for posterity.*

I would not pass back the list in this case in a `Future`.  You aren't going to be able to get the return until the job finishes.

If possible, I would pass *in* some sort of `BlockingQueue` so both the caller and the thread can access it:

```
final BlockingQueue<T> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<T>();
// build out job with the queue
threadPool.submit(new SomeJob(queue));
threadPool.shutdown();
// now we can consume from the queue as it is built:
while (true) {
   T result = queue.take();
   // you could some constant result object to mean that the job finished
   if (result == SOME_END_OBJECT) {
      break;
   }
   // provide intermediate results 
}
```

You could also have some sort of `SomeJob.take()` method which calls through to a `BlockingQueue` defined inside of your job class.

```
// the blocking queue in this case is hidden inside your job object
T result = someJob.take();
...
```

Comment: How is this relevant to Future<List<T>>?

Comment: It's exactly what I thought you were asking for.  Typically we just keep a list of `Futures`.  But there is no way to find the first one  that finishes so we can get incremental results.  The ECS accomplishes this @mikea.

Comment: @mikea he misunderstood your question, and I don't necessarily blame him. It sounds like you actually want a `List<Future<T>>`.

Comment: Or maybe Gray implies, as I think, that a List<Future<T>> is probably a better suited structure ?

Comment: @Gray he has a `Future<List<T>>` and wants to receive incrementally the results that will compose the `List`.

Comment: @dystroy if that's what he's implying then he's totally right :-)

Comment: `BlockingQueue` would work, but there are multiple problems: a) you need to communicate the end of list with a special object (I hate this kind of stuff :) b) It's not possible to use the result of computation from multiple clients.

Comment: @mikea The end-of-list special object is a common pattern although I agree it's a bit strange.  The alternative is an additional done boolean or something -- more unpleasant and certain more complicated.  Putting something into a `List` is the same as a `BlockingQueue`.  I'm not sure how my answer makes the remoting more complicated.

Comment: @mikea Can you explain your architecture a bit more?  You are fetching results from servers for the `List`.  Why can't the threads fetch the results from the servers and just add to the `BlockingQueue`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

1. In the thread that populates the List, make it thread-safe by wrapping the list using `Collections.synchronizedList`
2. Make the list publically available, but not modifiable by adding a public method to the thread which returns the list, but wrapped by `Collections.unmodifiableList`
3. Instead of giving clients a Future>, give them a handle to the thread, or some kind of wrapper of it, so that they can call the public method above.

Alternatively, as Gray has suggested, `BlockingQueue`s are great for thread coordination like this. This may require more changes to your client code, however.

Comment: Unfortunately the list doesn't communicate progress back to the client at all.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to Observables you can take a look at twitter's approach.

They use [Spool](https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/master/util-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/concurrent/Spool.scala), which is an asynchronous version of the [Stream](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream).

Basically it is a simple trait similar to the `List`

```
trait Spool[+A] {

  def head: A

  /**
   * The (deferred) tail of the spool. Invalid for empty spools.
   */
  def tail: Future[Spool[A]]
}
```

that allows you to do functional stuff like `map`, `filter` and `foreach` on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Future is really designed to return a single (atomic) result, not for communicating intermediate results in this manner. What you will really want to do is to use multiple futures, one per batch.

We have a similar requirement where we have a bunch of things that we need to get from different remote servers, and each will come return at different times. We don't want to wait until the last one has returned, but rather process them in the order they return. For this we created the [AsyncCompleter](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlassian-util-concurrent/src/master/src/main/java/com/atlassian/util/concurrent/AsyncCompleter.java) which takes an `Iterable<Callable<T>>` and returns an `Iterable<T>` that blocks on iteration, completely abstracting usage of the `Future` interface.

If you look at how that class is implemented, you'll see how to use a `CompletionService` to receive results from an `Executor` in the order in which they become available, if you need to build this for yourself.

edit: just saw that the second half of Gray's answer is similar, basically using an ExecutorCompletionService